# Aplicar desenfoque (blur) a un botón, excepto al texto del mismo - HTML5 y CSS3

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, web

Lo que quiero hacer es que un elemento `<button></button>` se desenfoque cuando el cursor del mouse pase por encima de él. **Así como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pero sin que se afecte o se ponga borroso el texto del boton. 


Gracias**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Propuesta de solucion

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        span{
          position: absolute;
          top: 37px;
          left: 30px;
          color: black;
        }
        button{
          
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
        }
        .base{
          position: relative;
        }
        button:hover{
          filter: blur(1px);
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="base">
      <button></button>
      <span>Hola</span>
    </div>
      
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Explicación**

- Primero envolvemos dentro de un `div` principal, tanto el `button` como un `span` que contenga el texto que deseas mostrar sin que se vea afectado por el `blur`
- Al `div` le damos una propiedad de `position relative` para que sea ubicado siguiendo el acomodo del resto de los elementos
- Al `span` que contiene el texto le damos una posición absoluta para poderlo ubicar a voluntad en un lugar especifico, como este mismo hace uso de esta propiedad y valor no sigue el acomodo regular de los elementos de la página y lo podemos mover y acomodar a conveniencia
- Del mismo modo al texto le colocamos medidas tanto en `top` como en `left` para establecer en cuantos pixeles se moverá en cada dirección y posicionarlo encima de la estructura del botón
- Al `button` le establecemos una medida tanto de altura como de anchura para poder
  observar el efecto (es decir en este punto solo estamos haciendo mas grande el botón, así que es netamente tu elección que medidas pongas)
- Finalmente aplicamos el `filter` con un `blur` de `1px` al `button`